# Firefox doesn't play facebook Gif images

Tags: firefox, images, facebook, gif

Firefox doesn't play Facebook GIF images. They look like static JPGs.
I tried changing my firefox profile (`firefox.exe -P`), and it works fine in another profile.
I restarted firefox with add-ons disabled, but to no benefit.

What is causing this to happen?

Comment: Open `about:config` in a new tab. What is the value of the `image.animation_mode` setting? http://kb.mozillazine.org/Animated_images_in_RSS_feeds_%28Thunderbird%29#Using_about:config

Comment: Value is Normal

Comment: That's a good thing isn't it?

Comment: i can't open any Gif image to display

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install MP4 H.264 codec and probe https://www.youtube.com/html5?gl=BR&hl=pt after reboot firefox. This is commented in http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=14535065#p14535065

Comment: How would OP install an MP4 H.264 codec, and would that help given that another profile plays the gifs correctly?

Comment: Have you all checked items in youtube test site? In this case may be caused for some installed plug-ins or custom configurations. "Refresh Firefox..." option is not the solution for you?

Comment: I see that facebook GIF player need H.265 codec. If you can't see any GIF the problem is other. I add this answer because it's specific for the facebook gifs problem.

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me, had another pc with same problem and this setting in about:config fixed it

media.directshow.enabled set to true (mine was false for some reason)

Comment: This does not answer the proposed questions.  Comments should only be submitted to the comment section.  if you cannot submit a comment, because of your reputation, don't submit a comment.

Comment: This does solve the problem , if you read irt carefully, i had the same problem, and this is not a workaround, but the reason it failed was that setting. Of course you dont know becqause you dont have the problem, let the ones that have judge if this is the solution, how could you know?

Comment: This option doesn't appear to me. The closest thing I could find was `media.directshow.enabled`, which is already on. I'm on Firefox 50.1.0, ubuntu 16.04.